# Offline bookmarks in my maps in Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, google-my-maps

I have a map in mymaps of google. I have added some bookmarks to it because I am going to a trip and wanted to highlight the places I'm going. The thing is those bookmarks are not accessible offline.

I know google has the option to download an area and to look at it offline. But that option does not include the bookmarks and its not on the mymaps app.

The other option I tried is exporting the bookmarks to kmz and imported to maps.me app. The problem with this app is that there are so many icons and places and the bookmarks icon is not really highlighted. I wish they had an option to hide all the other data.

How do I save the bookmarks offline in Google Maps?

Comment: I removed the portion of the question seeking a recommendation, as that aspect was off-topic.